# Powershell renaming special directories recursively

Tags: windows, powershell, explorer

I got this folder structure

C:\Users\myUser\Desktop
including folders called

- BL-100
- BL-105
- BL-108

and so on...
most BL-folders storing a file.xml, but not all.

So on Desktop are much folders starting with BL- and the most, but not all, storing a file.xml.

Now I want to search all folders which are starting with BL- and store a file.xml and rename those folders to RG-100, RG-105, RG-108 and so on

At the moment I got this script:

```
foreach($Directory in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\myUser\Desktop -Recurse | Where-Object{($_.Name.Substring(0,3) -eq 'BL-')}){

}
```

This does not work and is showing me error: Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

Anyone can help please?

Comment: `$_.Name -like 'BL-*'`.  NB: Substring may fail if it can't complete the operation; e.g. `'1'.Substring(0,2)`.

Comment: In addition to @john comment (which is the answer), to understand the reason of this error think what happens with a folder named "AB" (just two characters). Now `length` parameter is out of range (string is just two characters long and you're asking for 3 characters)

Comment: That worked very well, thank you @john!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because SubString fails for some reason.  The most likely reason would be if the string is not long enough; e.g. if you had a folder with a 1 character long name.  To see what I mean, try running: `'1'.Substring(0,2)`.

To avoid this, instead you could use the `like` operator.  e.g.

```powershell
foreach($Directory in (
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop' -Recurse `
    | Where-Object{($_.Name -like 'BL-*')}
)){
    #...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop" -directory -Filter "BL-*"
```